# How do I get Blender working with AMD OpenCL on Linux?

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux

I am using Arch Linux and am trying to use GPU Rendering in Blender. In the Arch Linux Wiki from Blender I read that I need either the **AMDGPU-PRO** or the **opencl-amd** package. So I installed the **opencl-amd** package and `clinfo` shows one platform with OpenCL 1.2.

But when I start Blender and change the Renderer to Cycles Render, it crashes. Showing the error
`amdgpu_device_initialize: amdgpu_query_info(ACCEL_WORKING) failed (-9)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

It is also crashing when I go to *Settings > System* with the same error message.

Blender Crash Log: https://pastebin.com/uaGcZAZ2

I have a RX 580 and using open-source amdgpu drivers on Arch linux.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem since an update at the beginning of the week. I'm unsure if the amdgpu_query_info() function is part of the blender source or if it's in the AMD opencl libraries that get ripped out of the proprietary driver and re-packaged as opencl-amd. AMD Radeon Pro WX-5100 was working a treat until a few days ago :( Mowley :)

Comment: I've been (unsuccessfully) trying to find where this is being tracked, assuming its not purely a problem with the opencl-amd package. I haven't tried installing the *-pro drivers, but if it's reproducible there I imagine it's time for a report to amd

Answer (score 1):

Having done some more poking around I have specifically pinned it down to only the libdrm update, downgrading to libdrm 2.4.93-1 is currently a functioning workaround.

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60061

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this error since `opencl-amd 18.30.641594` and `libdrm 2.4.94`. Rolling back to `opencl-amd 18.30.633530` and `libdrm 2.4.93` — as suggested in the [comments on the opencl‑amd package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencl-amd/) — seems to work for the time being.

Comment: The Downgrading fixed the crashing when I select Radeon ProRender. But now I get a CoreError when I try to render a scene. [Error](https://pastebin.com/JBgrdHmJ)

Comment: @Sakkaku I've not used Radon ProRender; is it possible that is a ProRender specific issue? Does GPU rendering with Cycles work?

Comment: It seems to be a problem from ProRender. GPU Rendering with Cycles works now in Blender.