# "No compatible GPUs found" - Arch Linux

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

When I open Blender through terminal it has no error messages, however when I open settings I am greeted by this message.

[image: Screenshot]

I am using an AMD Radeon R9 390X graphics card with the amdgpu driver. I know that my GPU is supported.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Hey @BetoOrouke, would you mind marking my answer as accepted if it answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install the proprietary AMDGPU-PRO drivers, or at least the OpenCL part of it. The quick fix is to install [opencl-amd](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencl-amd/) from AUR:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/opencl-amd.git
cd opencl-amd
makepkg -s
sudo pacman -U opencl-amd-*-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

(You might have to downgrade libdrm for opencl-amd to work, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118007/how-do-i-get-blender-working-with-amd-opencl-on-linux/118372#118372).)

*Note that Arch Linux is not officially supported by AMDGPU-PRO.*

#### Resources

- [Arch Wiki: "Blender does not show the AMD card as an OpenCL rendering device"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Blender#Blender_does_not_show_the_AMD_card_as_an_OpenCL_rendering_device)
- [Arch Wiki: AMDGPU PRO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#AMDGPU_PRO)